# Displaying content based on in app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have coded in app purchases into my app but I want to use a different view controller to show content based on whether the user has purchased the item or not

In my ViewController I am using this simple IF statement but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything else I need to be doing?

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"productIdentifier"])
    {

        label.text = @"Purchased";

    }

    else {

        label.text = @"Not Purchased";



    }
```

I have another file called **IAPHelper.m** where the In App Purchase is coded, there is a method in there for NSUSerDefaults like this:

```
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {


    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];



}
```

**EDIT**

If it helps, there is a UITableView in my app that manages to show content based on whether the user has made a purchase or not. The statement that controls this is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = product.localizedTitle;

    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

    if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

        labelPrice.text = @"Purchased";




    } else {



        labelPrice.text = @"Not Purchased";

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Changing the text of a label is not going to cause you to "use a different view controller."

Comment: There is nothing in your code to prove that you are in fact changing the value of the user defaults key `@"isPurchase"`. It is impossible to see what you might be doing wrong unless you show what you are in fact doing.

Comment: @matt I have edited my question, hope that can help

Comment: Yes, that shows clearly one thing you're doing wrong. `productIdentifier` and `@"productIdentifier"` do not match, so you're not checking the same user default that you're setting.

Comment: @matt I understand the issue, could you help me with the code because I'm a novice at this and would appreciate some direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@"productIdentifier"` is a string literal in the first block of code, but `productIdentifier` is a variable in the second.

Ha ok then… **Edit #3**

The reason it's working in your table is because you're accessing the `productPurchased` method in your current IAPHelper using:

```
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier];
```

Similarly, use:

```
// Index should equal 0 if there's only one product…
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:index];

if([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

    label.text = @"Purchased";

} else {

    label.text = @"Not Purchased";

}
```

Comment: So what should I change?

Comment: Change @"productIdentifier" in the first block of code to a productIdentifier variable.  And access the contents of that productIdentifier variable through an instance of iAPHelper.

Comment: Thanks for the logic but Im quite a novice developer so could you show me in code perhaps? I'd really appreciate that

Comment: Thanks for that! I have tried it but the code is crashing on this line if(![userDefaults boolForKey:mainDelegate.productIdentifier]) {

Comment: Did you create the instance of the app delegate within both view controllers like I suggested and declare "productIdentifier" in the appDelegate?  And what does the crash say?

Comment: See my edited answer for a UITableView in my app. Does that help? Basically I need that code to work ina  UIViewController

Comment: Okay, thanks for the edit, I have done that but getting Use of undeclared identifier 'product'

Comment: You need to include SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; the same way you did in the table view…  But is the table (and thus the _product array) also in the ViewController class?

Comment: Hmm, the code seems ok but its crashing. Not getting a crash error but if I put that code into the UITableView to test it says 'Implicit conversion of BOOL (aka 'signed char') to NSString is dissallowed with ARC

Comment: Oh, I though product purchased would return a string not a boolean… One last edit then...

Comment: That code doesn't work. Do I need to import any other files or code into this view controller?

Comment: Like I asked a few comments ago, is the table (and thus the _product array) also in the ViewController class?

Comment: I have declared NSArray *_products; in the ViewController same as Uitableview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44818/discussion-between-lyndsey-scott-and-omar)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to a different view based on whether the user has purchased the IAP, the following code works with a Storyboard based app. (You never specified, so I'm assuming that's what you're using)

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//self.productIdentifier needs to be defined with the productIdentifier to test.
 if([userDefaults boolForKey:self.productIdentifier])// **Removed** the !. With a ! this would return that the user hasn't purchased it, when they did.
{

    //User has purchased
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"purchasedView" sender:self];//You must set up a segue in the storyboard file first. (Control drag from files owner (orange box) onto the desired view. Then click on the new arrow. Then on the attributes inspector, name your segue id to "purchasedView"

}

else {

    //User has not purchased IAP.
//Optionally stay on this view.
}
```

**Edit**
New code

```
int indexNumberOfProduct = 1;//Change to whatever you need
SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:indexNumberOfProduct];


if ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]) {

    labelPrice.text = @"Purchased";




} else {



    labelPrice.text = @"Not Purchased";

}
```

Please mark this answer correct if it helps you.
Thanks

Comment: I tried this but it's not working for me. Product has been purchased but content hasn't changed. Do I need to import any other files?

Comment: Use breakpoints to determine if that block of code is even being called. If the code isn't being called, that's likely your biggest issue.

Comment: I have used breakpoints and it is calling that block of code, just doesnt seem to be doing anything with it

Comment: Oh I see what you are doing wrong. You need to check the boolForKey value for the correct product identifier, not @"isPurchase" So your code should look like:

Comment: NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 if(![userDefaults boolForKey:productIdentifier])
{

    //User has purchased
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"purchasedView" sender:self];//You must set up a segue in the storyboard file first. (Control drag from files owner (orange box) onto the desired view. Then click on the new arrow. Then on the attributes inspector, name your segue id to "purchasedView"

}

else {

    //User has not purchased IAP.
//Optionally stay on this view.
}

Comment: It says Use of undeclared identifier 'productIdentifier' - sorry im quite new to objective-c, appreciate your help. What would I need to add to declare it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit but Im still unsure of how to define self.productidentifier

Comment: Create a property in your .h file. Use the following code for that. @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productIdentifier; Then, you need to set the value of self.productIdentifier = the product identifier that you pass to your IAP helper class

Comment: Thank you, please see my edited answer above, getting there but crashing

Comment: I can't tell you why it's crashing without knowing where it's crashing, along with what it's telling you. Sorry

Comment: See my edited answer below for another area in my app where a different statement is working. Does that help at all?

Comment: Edited my answer to use your RageIAPHelper class

Comment: Hmm, your code made the label change to @"Not Purchased" regardless of whether it has purchased or not

Comment: One thing to also bare in mind is that i have to declare NSArray *_products; in the UITableView